# Video uploaded with the native media uploader gives Error 404

Tags: media, 404-error, media-library, videos

I created a `shortcode` to make an HTML5 player insert into my post, but my problem is when I attempt to view a video that I've uploaded with the native `Media Uploader`, I get a file not found error. The test video I used is an `.mp4`.

Is there a block on using videos in the `Media Uploader` that needs to get removed?

This does not appear to be a file permission issue, because the file uploads. When I browse the remote server via FTP, I see my file was added into the `/wp-content/uploads` directory.

Any reason why it wouldn't show up by accessing the file from the browser directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. It wasn't a `Wordpress` problem, but a server issue.

I had to add the file extension `.mp4` with MIME type `video/mp4` in the MIME types of the IIS server.

Here is the link I found with the steps to correct the issue:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1470612.aspx/1

```
 1) Select the site to configure in IIS, right click and select "Properties" 
 2) Under HTTP Headers Tab, select "File Types" under the MIME Map section and select "New Type" 
 3) Type ".flv" as the associated extension and "video/x-flv" as the content type or "flv-application/octet-stream" I'm not sure on which one gives here.
 4) for .mp4 files type ".mp4" as the extension and "video/mp4" as the mime type (this one I tested personally) 
 5) Select "OK",  
 6) type services.msc, find the "World Wide Web Publishing Service" and click
 on the restart icon on top or open up and choose restart
```